# Looking for a hash function (not necessarily cryptographic) where similar inputs return dissimilar outputs

Tags: hash, diffusion

I have the need to take a string and return a color. One requirement is that the same name always returns the same color. Another is that similar names should not return similar colors.

I understand that a property of cryptographic hash functions is that small changes to the input result in large changes to the output (diffusion). This seems like the property I need. However, I don't require the hashing function to be cryptographic is any other sense (it can be easily reversible).

Does anyone have suggestions for how to write a function with this property? Are there existing cryptographic functions that I could use? Thank you.

Comment: MD5 (despite i is not recommended for cryptographic purposes, it suites your requirements), SHA-256, SHA-512, BLAKE2, Whirlpool - they all suite requirements you have described.

Comment: That's great, thank you. Do you know if there are non cryptographic hash functions that have the properties I need?

Comment: @solowt there are, but it is unclear if they would be easier to use. There are at least two relevant concepts: One is that of a "chaotic map" --- small changes in the input lead to large changes in the output. The other is of a random walk that "mixes quickly", e.g. (like a cryptographic hash) one can expect the output after a few iterations will look uniform. The only reason I would not use a hash function though was if I already had a working implementation, and had noticed the hash function calls needed optimizing. Cryptographic hash functions are surprisingly fast though.

Comment: it's also worth mentioning that I don't know enough about "off the shelf" impls of the two concepts I described. There are many for hash functions of course.

Comment: @solowt: MD5 is not cryptographically secure. It was designed for cryptographic purposes. But it hast weak collision resistance and is not used in any serious cryptographic use cases.

Comment: Just crc32 does pretty much exactly what you're asking for.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I'll look into crc32 and md5. Appreciate the help.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because This is not about Cryptographic hash functions. This better suits to CS.

Comment: Thanks for your help KELALAKA, appreciate it, keep up the good work.